# System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException with Newtonsoft.Json in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, json, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Project UWP. I need to parse data in json format with Newtonsoft.Json, taking method Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() with Converter. I implement CustomCreationConverter and method ReadJson().
In Release after optimasation it does not work. And I have sush errors as:
"The value of the local variable or the "reader" argument can not be obtained because it is not available at this execution point, it may have been discarded during optimization. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader"

[image]

I want to try adding runtime directivesin in rd.xml, but don't sure what I should what need to add.

Comment: Error you mention you see only in debugger and it is most likely not related to the problem. How exactly it does not work?

Comment: Error is System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException. It failed on method  ReadJson().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps are compiled using .NET Native tool chain by default when they're compiled in Release mode. .NET Native compiler does some optimalizations (for example removes any classes, fields and so on that haven't been referenced anywhere) and generates static code, however Reflection uses dynamic features of .NET. So in order get rid of the `System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException` you'll have to write some [Runtime Directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600639(v=vs.110).aspx).

There is also a good series of five blog posts about this issue on .NET Blog:

1. [.NET Native Deep Dive: Dynamic Features in Static Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/20/net-native-deep-dive-dynamic-features-in-static-code/)
2. [.NET Native Deep Dive: Help! I Hit a MissingMetadataException!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/21/net-native-deep-dive-help-i-hit-a-missingmetadataexception/)
3. [.NET Native Deep Dive: Help! I Didn’t Hit a MissingMetadataException!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/22/net-native-deep-dive-help-i-didnt-hit-a-missingmetadataexception/)
4. [.NET Native Deep Dive: Making Your Library Great](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/23/net-native-deep-dive-making-your-library-great/)
5. [.NET Native Deep Dive: Optimizing with Runtime Directives](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/24/net-native-deep-dive-optimizing-with-runtime-directives/)

I suggest reading all of them since it could help you to understand what is happening and how to prevent experiencing similar issues in the future.

Comment: By far the scariest part of this issue is that a Debug build and a Release build behave differently.  This reduces my confidence that what we ship is actually going to work since it's basically a different app than what we developed and tested. This is a huge no-no by any standard and am surprised decision makers at Microsoft find this acceptable.

Comment: Well the same applies for Android and iOS where linker removes some unnecessary code like here. Using .NET Native or linker makes the app smaller in size and faster. They should however make developers know about these issues and tell them they should test their app even in Release mode.